# I am attempting to use Junit, mockito and PowerMock to create a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am attempting to use Junit, mockito and PowerMock to create a unit test

My problem is that one of the classes which i am attempting to mock is returning a null object

This is my code

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClientBuilder.class)
public class SolrPopulateApplicationTest {

   @Mock
   ClientConfig clientConfig;

   @Mock
   Client client;

   @Mock
   Response response;

   @Mock
   JerseyClient jerseyClient;

   @Mock (answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
   JerseyWebTarget jerseyWebTarget;

   @InjectMocks
   @Autowired
   SolrPopulateApplication solrPopulateApplication;

   @Test
   public void indexTest(){

       PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClientBuilder.class);

       ClientBuilder cli = Mockito.mock(ClientBuilder.class);

    when(ClientBuilder.newClient(Matchers.any())).thenReturn(client);

       when(jerseyClient.target(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(jerseyWebTarget);

       when(jerseyWebTarget.path(Matchers.anyString())
               .queryParam(Matchers.anyString(),Matchers.anyString())
       .request(Matchers.anyString())
               .header(Matchers.anyString(),Matchers.anyString())
       .post(Matchers.any())).thenReturn(response);

       boolean var = solrPopulateApplication.index("test","test");

   }
}
```

When a debug breakpoint is placed after all the mocks should have been setup i get the following

```
    client = {Client$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$7f4c6946@1705} "client"
response = {Response$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b85fdf42@1704} "response"
jerseyWebTarget = {JerseyWebTarget$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$7d7091b9@1703} "null"
solrPopulateApplication = {SolrPopulateApplication@1702} 
jerseyClient = {JerseyClient$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6437ba91@1701} "jerseyClient"
cli = {ClientBuilder$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$20196b6d@1700} "Mock for ClientBuilder, hashCode: 2080643905"
this = {SolrPopulateApplicationTest@1695}
```

as you can see the jerseyWebClient is a NULL and this is causing a nullpointerexception when i try to run the test.

I have tried removing (answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) from the @mock statement and this makes no difference.

The method being tested actually calls a interface which implements the JerseyWebTarget class. I have made sure I am trying to mock the right class by putting a debugger in the JerseyWebTarget class to make sure its stopping on the method which is being called via the interface.

can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: You should include your import statements too so that your example is complete. I'm unfamiliar with PowerMock and for all I know, both PowerMock and Mockito could contain a Mock annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using the Mockito `@Mock` annotation...

To use the Mockito `@Mock` annotation, you have to execute a particular line of code before each test. You can do this in a set up method:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

You also have to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` but as you are using the `PowerMockRunner` then this may not be necessary.

I would recommend that you avoid using PowerMock if at all possible, or at least get your mock working with Mockito before moving on to write the test with PowerMock. I quote the following from the [PowerMock wiki](https://github.com/jayway/powermock):

> Please note that PowerMock is mainly intended for people with expert knowledge in unit testing. Putting it in the hands of junior developers may cause more harm than good.

Unless there is a very specific reason why PowerMock is required here, avoid it. For example, you could pass the `JerseyWebTarget` into the constructor of your `SolrPopulateApplication` instead of making a direct call to `ClientBuilder` inside the class you are testing.

Furthermore, it's possible that PowerMock and Mockito will not always play nice together. For example, see [this bug](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/434).

Comment: One of the methods being mocked is a static
is powermock required for mocking static methods?

Comment: PowerMock is required for mocking static methods. I'm suggesting that you should AVOID mocking the static method. Instead, wrap the static method call in an instance method of an object that you create. This instance method can now be mocked without PowerMock. Better still, don't call the method inside the class you are testing - pass the result of the method into the classes constructor.